# rails checkbox saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have seven checkboxes, one representing each day of the week...
I'd like the user to check any amount of boxes, and have it save a number representing that day... (like monday 1, tuesday 2, etc.) and it save as an individual record in the db... so if they check 5 days, 5 new records..

however, my issue is when they check a few boxes, the 0's also get entered that weren't checked (the default value) so each time 7 new records are being added.

can anyone point me in the right direction?

the checkboxes are part of a nested form, and I tried a reject if but when the other fields are invalid on reload the checkboxes won't show up that were blank.

Answer (score 0):

What helper method are you using to generate those checkboxes?  Whatever it is, it's creating hidden default values that'll get sent to the server if the boxes aren't checked.  Usually it's what you want, but sometimes...

If you look at the docs for that function, there's probably a `:default => :off` (or something like that) option to disable those defaults.  Or you could try using [check_box_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag), which doesn't seem to generate default inputs.  And if neither of those work for you, it's really not a big deal to write yourself a checkbox in plain old HTML.

Hope that helps!

Comment: <%= builder.check_box :day, {}, val%> this is what i use

Comment: the default value is 0, which the docs say web browsers shouldn't send them.

Comment: @BenFrank - Yep.  It's that [check_box](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box) tag that's making the default "0" value.  My quick read through the linked docs didn't show any option to turn that off, so you'll want to look at check_box_tag instead.  Cheers!

Comment: @BenFrank - And you're right, but that Rails method was specifically designed to _always_ send a value (see the docs for check_box).  Imagine if you had a model with a boolean attribute; if your browser only sent "true" values you could always turn it on, but then you could never turn it off!

Comment: how would I use the check_box tag with my builder.check_Box object, and :day method though? I need that since it's a nested form.

Comment: @BenFrank - You'll need to set the field name to the right "nested" name (something like `mymodel[day]` - check your current HTML for the exact name), and you'll need some function `has_day?` to get whether each day should be checked or not. Then you can use something like: `check_box_tag('mymodel[day]', daycode, mymodel.has_day?(daycode))`